# Issue on these checkboxes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jgec5xmw/) checkboxes which I can't find a working solution. I know the answer is very short and simple but I just can't fix it thats why I need some help here.

In my code, I have a class that adds a fake checkbox (I did not hide the inputs for testing purpose) and a jQuery .click() event which function is to add the checked state class to the fake checkbox when clicked, and vice versa.

**CSS**

```
.fake-checkbox { /*...*/ }
.fake-checkbox.checked-state { /*...*/ }
```

**JS**

```
(function($) {
  $('.fake-checkbox').click(function() {
    // ...
  });
});
```

The problem is with those checkboxes that contained in a label is having conflict on clicked (please see my code to know what's going on).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the `.change()` method rather than `click` for checkbox inputs. Once a checkbox has been changed you need to determine if it's checked or not. If it **is** remove the `checked-state` class. If it **isn't** add the class.

```
$(function(){
    $('.fake-checkbox').change(function() {
        if( this.checked ){
            $(this).removeClass('checked-state');
        }else{
            $(this).addClass('checked-state');
        }
    });
});
```

if you're looking to change the class of the parent label, then use `.parent()` method:

`$(this).parent('label').addClass('checked-state');`
`$(this).parent('label').removeClass('checked-state');`

As per your comments if you have some instances where there are the checkbox is/isn't inside of a label you can just do more conditional checks. See the example below where it looks for the parent label to have the class `is-label`:

```
$(function(){
    $('.fake-checkbox').change(function() {
        if( this.checked ){
            $(this).removeClass('checked-state');
        }else{
            $(this).addClass('checked-state');
        }

        if( $(this).parent('label').hasClass('is-label') ){
            if( this.checked ){
                $(this).parent('label').removeClass('checked-state');
            }else{
                $(this).parent('label').addClass('checked-state');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah I knew about it, but there are times that the elements are not contained in a `<label>`. E.g - If the `selector` was clicked, the `input` is not checked. But this will work when they're both contained in a `<label>`. That's why I use the `click()` event instead.

Comment: You can simplify this to .change(function () { $(this).toggleClass("checked-state", this.checked); }); - See http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state

Comment: One thing, is it possible to use the jQuery `.change()` in my situation?

Comment: i've updated my answer to hopefully reflect your issue a litte more closely. you should always use `.change()` for checkbox changes

Comment: Sir I didn't add the class `.fake-checkbox` to the the parent `input`, instead, I've placed it on a `<span>` element. So if I use the `.change()` method in my case, it will not work.

Comment: A span does not have a change event.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to have any JavaScript with that layout. Basic CSS can style based on the state of the checkbox.

```css
.cb {
  display: none;
}
.fake-checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.cb:checked + .fake-checkbox {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input class="cb" type="checkbox">
  <span class="fake-checkbox"> </span>
</label>

<label>
  <input class="cb" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span class="fake-checkbox"> </span>
</label>
```

So what to do when it is not wrapped in a label? Well you can either wrap them in a label and be done, or you can shove a lot of JavaScript at it. So what I would do is add click events to the spans that are not wrapped in a label. That way the label ones work correctly. And all the JavaScript does is toggle the checkbox state. The filte/selection can be done any way, this is a quick solution.

```js
$(".fake-checkbox").filter( function() {
  return !$(this).parent().is("label");
}).on("click", function() {
  $(this).prev("input").click();
});
```

```css
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"],
.checkbox-inline input[type="checkbox"],
.input-group input[type="checkbox"]
{
  display: none;
}
.fake-checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
input:checked + .fake-checkbox {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="fake-checkbox"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <span class="fake-checkbox"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="fake-checkbox"></span>
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <span class="fake-checkbox"></span>
  </label>
  <hr>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon" style="position: relative;">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="fake-checkbox"></span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon" style="position: relative;">
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <span class="fake-checkbox"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @espascarello How cross browser compatible is that css psuedo selector?  I've seen the `+` CSS concatenation used in jQuery mobiles styling framework so I would assume it is widely compatible.

Comment: the + selector is as of css 2. It has support back to IE 7.0. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Comment: :checked is IE9 and adjacent sibling is like IE7?? Off top of my head.... I do not have time to look at the MDN support tables.

Comment: @mhodges I mean the `:checked` part.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon Yes, :checked is CSS3 and has support back to IE9. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked

Comment: Well checkboxes were around since the internet so lets stick to an all around jQuery working approach instead of pure CSS.

Comment: This one probably won't work when the elements aren't contained in a `<label>`. Addition is when the property `display: none` is added to the `input` (try it on the input-group-addon, talkin' bout my code) the field is messed up.

Comment: @ChainTrap Why not wrap your checkbox/span pairs in a `<label>`? Like what is prohibiting you from doing that?

Comment: @ChainTrap You can use visibility: hidden instead of display: none to keep the .input-group-addon width displaying properly. Also, if you absolutely cannot wrap them in a label, then use the CSS above, and add this one event handler to your javascript and remove everything else: $(".input-group-addon").on("click", function () { 
   $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").click(); 
  });

Comment: The sample HTML at the top of the jsfiddle had them wrapped in a label so that is what I went off of. So if it is not wrapped in a label, than you will need to use JavaScript.

Comment: @mhodges My reason would be: "There are times that the label isn't really required in some cases" like that one on the input-group-addon, it does not require including a label.

Comment: @ChainTrap See my most recent comment. It addresses every issue you have with this solution

Comment: @epascarello There are also checkboxes on my code which is not contained in a label that's why I'm using JavaScript here. I also knew those pseudo-classes and honestly I used it on my previous projects/codes but I think I'm better off with it and stick to JS but I'm just not good in this jQuery library :(

Comment: So you can still use the same CSS, just need to add a click event to cbs not in a label. I will post an answer that shows it.

Comment: @epascarello Yes please.. Chain Trap is obviously not understanding my comment haha

Comment: Updated it, if you really want to use classes, it is a bit more messy and you have to worry about checkbox state changing and the change event not being triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Default checkbox behavior is never easy to configure when you start to apply custom classes and delegate events through JavaScript/jQuery.  The safest and most exact way (cross-browser) of doing this is to cache a collection of target elements and then use the `.bind()`/`.on()` jQuery methods to trigger validation that will determine what you want to do.  Then, disable the default checkbox behavior and add your own listeners and behavior.  The updated example accounts for check-boxes that are not wrapped within a label.

[Updated Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/jgec5xmw/4/)

**References:**

[jQuery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

[jQuery .bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

[jQuery event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

*Consequently, this type of question alludes to reinventing the wheel.  There are some robust libraries that can achieve this task with greater ease, accuracy as well as much less implementation time.*

[icheck](http://icheck.fronteed.com/) is a great library for this type of thing.

```js
//Alexander Dixon - 09/28/2016

//Determine scope of your target inputs by isolating the DOM parent containers.
var masterContainer = $('div.checkbox, label.checkbox-inline, div.form-group, div.input-group, div.input-group-addon');
var allInputs = [];

//Cache all target inputs into an array collection.
masterContainer.each(function() {
    var inputs = $(this).find($('input[type="checkbox"]'));
    for (i = 0, z = inputs.length; i < z; i++) {
        allInputs.push(inputs[i]);
    }
});

//Confirm you targeted them all.
console.log(allInputs);

//Custom function to handle add class validation
function applyClasses(a) {
    $(a).each(function(i) {
        var spanToStyle = $(a[i]).closest($('label, div')).find('span.fake-checkbox') || $(a[i]).siblings('span.fake-checkbox');
        if ($(a[i]).is(':checked')) {
            spanToStyle.addClass('checked-state');
        } else {
            spanToStyle.removeClass('checked-state');
        }
    });
}

//Add new event to circumvent default labeled checkbox functionality and determines whether to add or remove a class
$('label').not($('.fake-checkbox')).on('keypress click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('i clicked it');
    if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        console.log(e.target);
        var elementClicked = ($(e.target).attr('class')) ? $(e.target).attr('class') : "label";
        //var elementClickedLabel = $(e.target).context.toString();
        console.log("element clicked: " + elementClicked);
        if ((elementClicked.match(/fake-checkbox/)) || (elementClicked.match(/label/))) {
            console.log('fake clicked');
            var closestCheckBox = ($(e.target).siblings('input[type="checkbox"]').length === 1) ? $(e.target).siblings('input[type="checkbox"]') : $(e.target).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
            console.log(closestCheckBox);
            if (closestCheckBox.is(':checked')) {
                closestCheckBox.prop('checked', false);
            } else {
                closestCheckBox.prop('checked', true);
            }
        }
        applyClasses($(allInputs));
    }
});

//Cache non-labeled checkboxes for precise control and DOM targeting/Event triggering.
var nonLabeledCheckboxes = $('div.input-group-addon').find('span.fake-checkbox');

$(nonLabeledCheckboxes).on('keypress click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('i clicked it');
    if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        console.log(e.target);
        var elementClicked = $(e.target).attr('class');
        var elementClickedLabel = $(e.target).context.toString();
        if (elementClicked.match(/fake-checkbox/)) {
            console.log('fake clicked');
            console.log($(e.target).siblings('input[type="checkbox"]'));
            var closestCheckBox = $(e.target).siblings('input[type="checkbox"]');
            if (closestCheckBox.is(':checked')) {
                closestCheckBox.prop('checked', false);
            } else {
                closestCheckBox.prop('checked', true);
            }
        }
        applyClasses($(allInputs));
    }
});

//Initialize on page load.
applyClasses($(allInputs));
```

```css
.fake-checkbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: -3px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index: 5;
    cursor: pointor;
}

.input-group-addon .fake-checkbox {
    top: 5px;
    left: 9px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fake-checkbox.checked-state {
    border-color: blue;
    cursor: pointor;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span class="fake-checkbox"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked>
            <span class="fake-checkbox"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="fake-checkbox"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" checked>
        <span class="fake-checkbox"></span>
    </label>
    <hr>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon" style="position: relative;">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span class="fake-checkbox"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon" style="position: relative;">
            <input type="checkbox" checked>
            <span class="fake-checkbox"></span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```